# hive(hadoop) auto increment (insert into values)

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

How to make auto increment or generate UUID for hive(hadoop) table?

for:

```
insert into ... values ...
```

not

```
insert into ... select ...
```

Thanks.

Comment: You mean an auto-increment that stays consistent whatever the number of Mappers involved? What about adding a dummy column with a constant value, then using an analytic function like `Row_Number() over (order by DummyCol) as RelativeRank`, then using the previous Max as offset, and hoping that there is no concurrent INSERT that will generate duplicates? That sounds both slow and dangerous.

Comment: Or, if you want sthg similiar to an Oracle sequence, you can use an UDF backed by an ACID database. Both complicated and slow *(ask anyone who tried to work with sequences at scale - can't get over 5000 values per second on Exadata, for instance)*

Comment: It's not good variants... the same INSERT INTO TEST( id, test1, test2, test3 ) SELECT MAX( id ) + 1, 3, 4, 5 FROM TEST;